# Cassandra: activating row cache for a column family seems to fail

Tags: caching, cassandra

I've got a bit of a problem activating row level cache for a big cassandra 1.1.2 cf:

If I run

```
update column family user_data with caching = 'ALL';
```

(no matter if i use quotes or not)

It says

```
515b08ac-89c5-3890-bcc1-60bf55f0228a
Waiting for schema agreement...
... schemas agree across the cluster
```

But afterwards, caching still seems to be off. 
I also activated it in the config file.
Describe also says that it is off:

```
create column family user_data
  with column_type = 'Standard'
  and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
  and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
  and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
  and read_repair_chance = 0.1
  and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
  and gc_grace = 864000
  and min_compaction_threshold = 4
  and max_compaction_threshold = 32
  and replicate_on_write = true
  and compaction_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'
  and caching = 'KEYS_ONLY'
  and column_metadata = [
    {column_name : 'content',
    validation_class : BytesType}]
  and compression_options = {'sstable_compression' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor'};
```

Using CQL to update it (ALTER TABLE user_data WITH caching='all';) does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.1.5 by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4561.  1.1.5 is going out to the mirrors today, but you can get it at http://people.apache.org/~slebresne/ before then.